# Stop STM32F4 RTC in debug

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4

A test was assigned to me by my professor.

In the test I need to make a STM32f4XX discovery to act like a clock by using the internal RTC and be able to stop it in any time and then the clock be able to resume the count (like a stopwatch).

One of the points of the test is be able to stop the program via the STMCube debugger like the suspend execution or a breakpoint, and when the execution is resumed the "clock" continues in the exact point it left.

Is it possible?

At this point, if I pause the execution in the debugger and then hit resume, the clock "jumps" to another second/minute just like I never paused it. Because the RTC is still running in the background.

According to the Reference manual of the chip, once the RTC starts, it can't be stopped until the chip is powered off.

Is it possible in any way ?

Comment: Typically every hardware peripherals have settings for how it should act in stop/sleep modes. If you can't find anything about that for the RTC peripheral, then maybe you need to use one of the general-purpose hardware timers instead.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin that was just the way how I was thinking to solve my problem, I just need to wait until my professor answers and clarify if it is a error in the exam or it is possible to use another timer besides the RTC.

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Lundin did you read the documentation of any STM32F4 micro or it is some kind of voodoo (cargo cult) advice?

Comment: @P__J__ I have read a whole lot of user manuals and have no desire to do so here, when the OP already did. Thus I posted a _comment_ about how general microcontroller hardware works and not an _answer_.

Comment: @Lundin ***`how general microcontroller hardware works`*** I do not know how it works in "general" in debug modes. Almost every manufacturer and almost every family does it different way

Comment: @P__J__ Nah, you just posted an answer which showed that this one work pretty much like every other part when it comes to timer-related peripherals (RTC, timer, PWM, watchdog etc etc). They call it "stop" or "freeze" or "halt".

Comment: I peeked in the manual now out of curiosity and 21.4 says that you can have it behave differently depending on RTC clock source. This is for low power modes though, not debugging. So the question is what should be stopping the RTC and what shouldn't.

Comment: @Lundin low power stop mode and the debuger stop mode are two completely different things. Name is the same, but it means something completely different

Comment: @P__J__ I know, hence "So the question is what should be stopping the RTC and what shouldn't". If the MCU and/or RTC should leave sleep mode by an external "keyboard wakeup" interrupt from GPIO etc, or through a debugger command over SWD. "Stopwatch" could mean anything.

Comment: @Lundin STM32 has a very powerful debug interface, but almost no one uses it as almost no one is bothered to read the documentation. People think that magic HAL functions (some kind of voodoo programming) is enough.

Comment: @Lundin ***`via the STMCube debugger like the suspend execution or a breakpoint`***

Comment: @P__J__ "One of the points of the test..." And the other points are...?

Comment: @P__J__ And regarding the so-called "HAL" bloatware being generally harmful, you are preaching to the choir :)

Comment: @Lundin I mean: people think if they use HAL then they do not have to know how the hardware works (I know many thousands of pages etc etc). It makes most of the HAL programmers voodoo zombies.

Comment: Sorry for this. after reading for a third time the manual of the chip im using (stm32F407) and finally found the register I was searching for...

Thanks to all. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug peripheral has special registers where you can program which peripheral to run or stop in the debug top mode. They are called "freeze registers"

So if you want RTC to be stopped when the processor is stopped by the breakpoint you need to program those registers.

[image]
[image]
[image]